# How to get the x and y location of a particular object or item on the current screen in python?

Tags: python, search, automation, location, screen

I am trying to write a simple automation program in python.
According to this project, the program code should find an object and gets its position as x and y value based on user’s input. For example: my current screen is desktop, if I give the input as recycle pin, it should search and find the recycle pin and get its x and y position from the desktop screen. or if I said python, it should find the x and y location of python application.
And I don’t want to do it by image recognition method, please tell some other ideas.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I don't think you can just say "Python, get recycle pin" unless you have defined it first. Everyone's operating systems are different, and so are their screen dimensions. Are you trying to make an automation program for yourself, or for anybody? If it is for anybody, you will probably have to have them configure it for their specific machine.

(Can't post as comment because not enough reputation, sorry!)